# how to make a list float left or not according to the size of the browser?

Tags: html, css

how to make  the li of a nav list float left or not according to the size of the browser?

Hi, I am new to html and I am reading the html and the css code of the website: http://www.quarryequipments.com/
I notice that if I make the browser size small, the li element  in the navigation will not float left, how do I make it out? 
thanks.

Comment: Sharath has given you the most "appropriate" answer to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a responsive navigation bar,when the width decreases the navigation bar adjusts according to it and that's how it should be. Else it wont properly fit on smaller widths.
They are using a framework called Foundation,which is a responsive framework. [Link](http://foundation.zurb.com/)